# Can't run dependent project

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, project, setup-project

I'm working with Intellij IDEA project. My main program is dependent on some database server inside the docker container, so to run project I firstly run "docker-compose" (`"RNAO Services"` configuration on the attached screen) and only after that I run my main configuration (`"RNAO Server"`).
[image]
What I want to do is to run docker compose before start of my main configuration.
I have tried to add docker compose configuration in the "before launch" list inside the main configuration after the "Build" step, but it just freezes on start. I think that the reason is that when I try to run docker compose configuration, it is not shown as running (no red square "stop" button available), but they are (I have access to the database inside the container).
Here is the project look when I start docker compose configuration:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

IDE will not run the configuration until all tasks from **Before launch** section have been terminated. There is a related request: [*IDEA-112294*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112294) *Before Launch -> Run Another Configuration Should Support Non-Terminating Before Launch Configurations* about it.